# How to convert a string to a ConsoleKeyInfo?

Tags: c#, console

I need to know what a string must look like to be excepted for a (ConsoleKeyInfo)Enum.Parse. Or a different way to convert a string to a ConsoleKeyInfo.

I've tried converting ConsoleKeyInfos to strings directly, but that just leaves me with a bunch of "ConsoleKeyInfo" string.
Converting to ConsoleKeyInfo.Key leaves me with the keys and is also not excepted by the parse.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strListTemp.Count; i++)
    {
    keyBinds.Add((ConsoleKeyInfo)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleKeyInfo), strListTemp[i]));
    }
```

strListTemp is a string list with converted ConsoleKeyInfos.
keyBinds is a ConsoleKeyInfo list.

The error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Type provided must be an Enum.
Parameter name: enumType'
```

It needs to be converted to a string and back because I need to save it in a file.
If there is a way to store ConsoleKeyInfos directly to a file, please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Emanuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ConsoleKeyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) has the `Serializable` attribute, which means that it can be saved to a file using a [`BinaryFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("my console key info.dat", FileMode.Create)) {
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fs, yourConsoleKeyInfo);
}
```

To deserialise, simply call `formatter.Deserialize`

---

If you want a string representation, you need to create a string with 5 things:

- a char indicating the value of the `KeyChar` property
- a number indicating the value of the `Key` property
- a boolean value indicating whether the shift modifier is pressed
- a boolean value indicating whether the alt modifier is pressed
- a boolean value indicating whether the control modifier is pressed

These 5 values can be separated by spaces in the string. To parse it, split the string by spaces and convert each of the values to their corresponding types, and pass them to the `ConsoleKeyInfo` constructor.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I used the BinaryFormatter and it worked, but I realized that I want to be able to change the values outside the program so I need it to be in a text file.
I have this: strListTemp.Add(Convert.ToString(keyBinds[i].KeyChar) + " " + Convert.ToString(keyBinds[i].Key) + " false false false"); I don't want any modifications to be possible so always having them on false is fine. But .key doesn't give a number. How do I get the number indicating the value of key?

Comment: @EmanueldeJong you can cast it to an `int`. `Key` is an enumeration. All enums can be casted to int. if you want all `false`, you don’t actually need to store it in the file.